# Анимация прелоадера

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]Есть прелоадер, его формат .gif. Все хорошо, все работает, но он отображается обычной картинкой, а не гифкой. В чем может быть проблема?
JS:

```
var preload = $("#main_preload"), 
w = $(window).width() / 2 - 30, 
h = $(window).height() / 2 - 30;
preload.html('<img src="../images/loader.gif" alt="load content."/>');
$(window).load(function () {
    setTimeout(function () {
        preload.animate({opacity: "0"}, 50, function () {
            preload.html("")
        });
        $("#wrapper").animate({opacity: "1"}, 50)
    }, 1000)
});
```

HTML:

```
<span id="main_preload"></span>
<div id="wrapper">
   <header></header>
   <div class ="middle"></div>
   <footer></footer>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#main_preload{
    position: fixed;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}

#wrapper {
    opacity: 0;
}
```

Comment: Ну вы хотя бы гифку покажите))

Comment: а в этом есть необходимость? просто обычная анимированная гифка

Comment: Да, необходимость есть. Потому что у вас обычный код и разметка. Кстати, в `html` было бы также неплохо показать, что такое `#wrapper`.

Comment: в wrapper входит классическая разметка, т.е. header, middle, footer

Comment: Пожалуйста, отразите это в вопросе. Не обязательно со стилями для начала, просто что бы понимать структуру.

Comment: Поправил в html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Все работает, как положено. Наверное, все же проблема в гифке?

```js
var preload = $("#main_preload"),
  w = $(window).width() / 2 - 30,
  h = $(window).height() / 2 - 30;
preload.html('<img src="https://i.gifer.com/9eFm.gif" alt="load content."/>');
$(window).load(function() {
  setTimeout(function() {
    preload.animate({
      opacity: "0"
    }, 1000, function() {
      preload.html("")
    });
    $("#wrapper").animate({
      opacity: "1"
    }, 1000)
  }, 2000)
});
```

```css
#main_preload {
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

#wrapper {
  opacity: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span id="main_preload"></span>
<div id="wrapper">
  <header></header>
  <div class="middle">Главный контент</div>
  <footer></footer>
</div>
```

Comment: мне ее скинули в скайпе и я ее просто сохранил, возможно я не так что-то сделал?

Comment: @aquido Что и приводит нас к моему первому комментарию. *Ну вы хотя бы гифку покажите))*

Comment: добавил гифку в вопрос

Comment: @aquido Ну так она не `gif`, а `png`.

Comment: но в проекте у меня она gif

Comment: @aquido Я рад, что в проекте она у вас `gif`. Вот ее, как в проекте и нужно загрузить сюда, дать ее нам. Вы же видите, `gif` из интернета в сниппете нормально работает.

Comment: исправил формат на gif

Comment: @aquido вы исправили расширение файла `png` на `gif`. Но ведь картинка все равно не двигается и она в формате `png`! Вы возьмите вашу **НАСТОЯЩУЮ gif картинку** и прикрепите к вопросу. Она ведь у вас в вопрос вставленная даже не двигается.